# How remove .php extension from codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

My link show this:

```
http://localhost/project/index.php
```

I want this:

```
http://localhost/project/
```

Do not display extension

Comment: the question didnt provide sufficient info when it was posted but this was later edited, will remove the comment, thanks for noticing

Comment: Read more about MVC Pattern

Comment: Check in `APPPATH.'config/config.php` file what is set for `$config['url_suffix'] = '';` option. Blank string is default. Making `$config['url_suffix'] = '';` from `$config['url_suffix'] = '.php';` would give you wanted result. But be aware, there's catch: you could break links in all view or controller files if (and I'd believe to) those are set with suffix.

Comment: What this has to do with mvc? @FaridulKhan

Answer (score 2):

You don't understand MVC pattern, there is no direct access to files within URL, everything is redirected to one page.

Full URL: `http://localhost/project/home/about`

root: `http://localhost/project`

controller: `home`

method inside given controller: `about`

Read more about MVC in Codeigniter's website: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html

Or here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter provide ***Routing rules/URI Routing*** for this.

You can achive this by adding variable to **$route** array in

*/application/config/routes.php* file

```
$old_path = 'home/about'; // no need to add .php to about

$new_path='home/about'; //or about or any other name you want

$route[$new_path] =$old_path;
```

Now you can visit page by only

> http://localhost/project/home/about

For more details :-

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html?highlight=route

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter's mvc works as project_folder/index.php/controller/function.

If you modify this behaviour with htaccess it might collapse the behaviour of the framework.

Learn how it works and get clarified. [This link](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html) might help you.

Answer (score -2):

Create a file with the name ".htaccess" just ".htaccess" NOT "test.htaccess" or so. 
Write this code in it ->

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Now you can link your sites like this -> `<a href="http://test/abc">Test</a>`

Comment: Your answer is right. But you can't do it with a framework. It might collapse 
the flow of the framework